# How to use a macro to generate compile-time unique integers?

Tags: rust, macros

I need several parts of a program, in different modules, to have a unique integer.

for example:

```
pub fn foo() -> u64 {
    unique_integer!()
}

pub fn bar() -> u64 {
    unique_integer!()
}
```

(`foo()` should never return the same as `bar()`, but the values themselves are meaningless and do not need to be stable across builds.  All invocations of `foo()` must return the same values, as must all invocations to `bar()`.  It is preferred, but not essential, that the values are contiguous.)

Is there a way of using a macro to do this?

Comment: mandatory https://xkcd.com/221/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to do something like this with [`once_cell`](https://docs.rs/once_cell/1.10.0/once_cell/index.html), using a static atomic variable as a counter:

```
use core::sync::atomic::{Ordering, AtomicU64};
use once_cell::sync::Lazy;

static COUNTER: AtomicU64 = AtomicU64::new(0);

fn foo() -> u64 {
    static LOCAL_COUNTER: Lazy<u64> = Lazy::new(|| COUNTER.fetch_add(1, Ordering::Relaxed));
    *LOCAL_COUNTER
}

fn bar() -> u64 {
    static LOCAL_COUNTER: Lazy<u64> = Lazy::new(|| COUNTER.fetch_add(1, Ordering::Relaxed));
    *LOCAL_COUNTER
}

fn main() {
    dbg!(foo()); // 0
    dbg!(foo()); // still 0
    dbg!(bar()); // 1
    dbg!(foo()); // unchanged - 0
    dbg!(bar()); // unchanged - 1
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=4257e2afc5651aa3fb47baaa796a4e28)

And, yes, the repeating code can be, as usual, wrapped in macro:

```
macro_rules! unique_integer {
    () => {{
        static LOCAL_COUNTER: Lazy<u64> = Lazy::new(|| COUNTER.fetch_add(1, Ordering::Relaxed));
        *LOCAL_COUNTER
    }}
}

fn foo() -> u64 {
    unique_integer!()
}

fn bar() -> u64 {
    unique_integer!()
}
```

Comment: This is likely the preferable solution. However if consistency between different runs of a single build is important, then this would introduce a race condition. I'm trying to think of a way around this, but I can not think of any solutions.

Comment: Thanks, I'd become fixated on it being generated at compile time, when that would be just an optimisation, and is not required for the functionality.

Answer (score 4):

You could compute a compile-time hash using the module path (which contains the crate and modules leading up to the file), the file name, column and line number of the macro invocation like this:

```rust
pub const fn hash(module_path: &'static str, file: &'static str, line: u32, column: u32) -> u64 {
    let mut hash = 0xcbf29ce484222325;
    let prime = 0x00000100000001B3;

    let mut bytes = module_path.as_bytes();
    let mut i = 0;

    while i < bytes.len() {
        hash ^= bytes[i] as u64;
        hash = hash.wrapping_mul(prime);
        i += 1;
    }

    bytes = file.as_bytes();
    i = 0;
    while i < bytes.len() {
        hash ^= bytes[i] as u64;
        hash = hash.wrapping_mul(prime);
        i += 1;
    }

    hash ^= line as u64;
    hash = hash.wrapping_mul(prime);
    hash ^= column as u64;
    hash = hash.wrapping_mul(prime);
    hash
}

macro_rules! unique_number {
    () => {{
        const UNIQ: u64 = crate::hash(module_path!(), file!(), line!(), column!());
        UNIQ
    }};
}

fn foo() -> u64 {
    unique_number!()
}

fn bar() -> u64 {
    unique_number!()
}

fn main() {
    println!("{} {}", foo(), bar()); // 2098219922142993841 2094402417770602149 on the playground
}
```

([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=e265eb6ee9f051cdc824ab99699caf53))

This has the benefit of consistent results, when compared to the top answer that can return different values depending on the order of invocation, and this is also entirely computed in compile time, which remove the runtime overhead of maintaining a counter.

The only downside to this is that you could get hash value collisions. But the chance is low. If you want, you could try implementing an algorithm that computes perfect hash values. The example shown uses the FNV algorithm which should be decent but not perfect.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can not use a regular macro for this. However, you might be able to find a procedural macro crate which might give this functionality.

##### That being said...

This **does not** count as safe rust, *but* if we are okay with throwing safety out the window then this should do the trick.

```rust
macro_rules! unique_u64 {
    () => {{
        struct PlaceHolder;
        let id = ::std::any::TypeId::of::<PlaceHolder>();
        unsafe { ::std::mem::transmute::<_, u64>(id) }
    }};
}
```

**This is probably undefined behavior**, but since we know that every type should have a unique `TypeId` it would have the desired effect. The only reason I know that this is even possible is because I have looked at the structure of `TypeId` and know it contains a single `u64` to distinguish types. However, there are currently plans to change `TypeId` from being a `u64` to something more stable and less prone to this kind of unsafe code. We have no guarantees on what the contents of `TypeId` might change to and when it does change it might silently fail if it still has the same size as a `u64`.

###### Alternatively,

We can achieve a similar result in safe rust by hashing the `TypeId`. Now, it slightly breaks the rules since we do not have any guarantee that it will always produce a unique result. However, it seems highly unlikely that 2 different `TypeId`s would hash to the same value. Plus this stays within safe rust and is unlikely to break for future releases of Rust.

```rust
macro_rules! unique_u64 {
    () => {{
        use ::std::hash::{Hash, Hasher};
        
        struct PlaceHolder;
        let id = ::std::any::TypeId::of::<PlaceHolder>();
        let mut hasher = ::std::collections::hash_map::DefaultHasher::new();
        id.hash(&mut hasher);
        hasher.finish()
    }};
}
```

Comment: As `TypeId` implements `Ord`, would there be a way of adding all the `TypeId`s to an ordered structure, such as a `BTreeSet`, and reading their index?  This would remove the need to hash or transmute.

Comment: you confuse implemented behavior and ub

Comment: Transmuting `TypeId` to `u64` is undefined behavior. Firstly it isn't `repr(transparent)` which already makes the transmute unsound, secondly even if it was `repr(transparent)` its documentation says it is deliberately opaque to hide the implementation detail. Using the hash value seems better IMO.

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly a macro but anyway it's a proposition:

```rust
#[repr(u64)]
enum Unique {
    Foo,
    Bar,
}

pub fn foo() -> u64 {
    Unique::Foo as u64
}

pub fn bar() -> u64 {
    Unique::Bar as u64
}
```

Compiler should warn you if you don't use a variant.

Comment: This answer has the downside that the enum needs to be maintained.  i.e. Third party code cannot generate `u64`s.

Comment: @fadedbee I don't think you can have third party code AND compile time generation.

Comment: @Stargateur: See my answer for details. The hash value depends on the crate, the modules that it is located in, the file name, and the exact location of invocation in the file.